# Google Earth Engine plug-in (for QGIS): Authorization error

Tags: google-earth-engine, qgis-plugins

I have installed the GEE plug-in for QGIS and I am struggling to even get beyond authorisation at the moment. I have an active GEE account to use the plugin. Posted below is the Authorization Error message I am receiving:

> Authorization Error
> Error 400: invalid_request.
> The version of the app you're using doesn't include the latest security features to keep you protected. Please make sure to download from a trusted source and update to the latest, most secure version.

Initially I was using QGIS 3.16.10... so I have since downloaded QGIS 3.22.7, and am still receiving the same error.

A QGIS pop-up is also displaying an *Authorization* message stating - GEE Python is not detected on this machine.

Comment: Which version of the QGIS EE plugin did you try to install?

Comment: Try uninstalling/reinstalling v0.0.5